# How to prevent a user from leaving comment to  another user

Tags: php, sql, restriction

Suppose I have a site where users can leave each other comments.

we have user A, user B and user C.
also, support user B has blocked user C.

user A leaves user B a comment, code is as follows:

```
$query = "insert into comments (author_id, profile_id, comment, date_posted) values(?, ?, ?, now())";
```

That is the query that that does the job. 
now user C goes to user B's page to leave a comment, but user B has blocked him from leaving comments.

Can't user C just leave a comment for another user, and just craft the request so he changes profile_id of to the user that has him blocked?

How can i prevent this?

Comment: You have to check if user is not in black list **before** you perform insert. Never trust any data comes outside

Comment: How are you storing the block? Your code has to check that mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make another query and a conditional with that result.  Create a query to get user B's blacklist `$blacklist` then check `if (!in_array('user C', $blacklist)) { execute insert query }`

Comment: `Create a query to get user B's blacklist $blacklist then check if (!in_array('user C', $blacklist))` --- why not to do that in a single query